# Add an admin role in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to know how to add an admin role by using devise gem. I ve already used it for normal users but not for admin role. I ve read this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-role. It is clearly mentioned about how to add the role of admin into the application. But i've some questions regarding that which are as follows:

1. How to specify that particular user is an admin (in my case i just want a private admin for controlling the activities in an app)?
2. How to do basic CRUD activities using admin role (i want CRUD activities for users and its contents)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have used the Devise, CanCan, and Rolify stack to do some admin stuff. It's more than what you need, but the benefits are awesome. A wiki on how to set it up [here](https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Tutorial).

If you want an admin, first give all your users a role, for example "member", then also give your admins a role, like "admin".

Then you can use devise checks like `current_user`, and you can also use Rolify stuff like `if @user.has_role? "admin"`

It's pretty boss

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. but actually i was thinking to do manually these admin stuff. So can u please explain me the step u mentioned to give roles to users.!!

Comment: i m actually a newbie to ror.. to i m not getting it properly.. like how to give roles.. i just want one admin and many members.. admin is just for controlling all the activities like deleting members... deleting members content... all these stuff..

Answer (score 0):

For an updated solution using **Rails 5**, [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) (CanCan doesn't look like it's supported anymore), check this out:

1. [RAILS 5: USER ACCOUNTS WITH 3 TYPES OF ROLES – DEVISE, RAILS_ADMIN,
   CANCANCAN](https://codepany.com/blog/rails-5-user-accounts-with-3-types-of-roles-devise-rails_admin-cancancan/)

Here is an alternate solution that is worth mentioning; it uses Rails [Pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) and *has_secure_password* and is worth mentioning:

2. [Implementing Roles and Permissions in Ruby on Rails](http://culttt.com/2016/01/20/implementing-roles-and-permissions-in-ruby-on-rails/)

The advantage of using CanCanCan is that it decouples authorization from user roles whereas a lot of people find Pundit easier to work with less invasive. Both are good.

Both address what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

Current rails don't have a way to add except with gems like CancanCan and rolify. follow the steps in their documentation also setting the admin_role for all other users to false and use rails console to set your desired user to true
The video below was very helpful.

[Web crunch tutorial, Admin role](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PmkBBRq6jQ0&t=770s)